# jQuery Conflict issue - stopping a script running

Tags: javascript, jquery, conflict

I have a 'back to top' button that appears on the following page:

http://demov3.joostrap.com/k2

When you scroll down it appears (fixed) in the bottom right hand corner.

When on the homepage http://demov3.joostrap.com it doesn't work.

I think it may be a conflict with the slider on the homepage (because if I disable the slider, it works), something to do with the following scripts - but I am puzzled.

**Scroll to top javascript**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#totop").hide();
        jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
            if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                jQuery('#totop').fadeIn();
            } else {
                jQuery('#totop').fadeOut();
            }
        });     
        jQuery('#totop').click(function(){
            jQuery("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 660, 'easeInOutExpo');
            return false;
        });
});
```

**Slider javascript**

```
/*
Sequence.js (http://www.sequencejs.com)
Version: 1.0
Author: Ian Lunn @IanLunn
Author URL: http://www.ianlunn.co.uk/
Github: https://github.com/IanLunn/Sequence

This is a FREE script and is available under a MIT License:
http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php

Sequence.js and its dependencies are (c) Ian Lunn Design 2012 - 2013 unless otherwise stated.

Sequence also relies on the following open source scripts:

- jQuery imagesLoaded 2.1.0 (http://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded)
    Paul Irish et al
    Available under a MIT License: http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php

- jQuery TouchWipe 1.1.1 (http://www.netcu.de/jquery-touchwipe-iphone-ipad-library)
    Andreas Waltl, netCU Internetagentur (http://www.netcu.de)
    Available under a MIT License: http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php

- Modernizr 2.6.1 Custom Build (http://modernizr.com/)
    Copyright (c) Faruk Ates, Paul Irish, Alex Sexton
    Available under the BSD and MIT licenses: www.modernizr.com/license/
    */(function(e){function n(n,s,o,f){function d(){l.afterLoaded();l.settings.hideFramesUntilPreloaded&&l.settings.preloader!==undefined&&l.settings.preloader!==!1&&l.frames.show();if(l.settings.preloader!==undefined&&l.settings.preloader!==!1)if(l.settings.hidePreloaderUsingCSS&&l.transitionsSupported){l.prependPreloadingCompleteTo=l.settings.prependPreloadingComplete===!0?l.settings.preloader:e(l.settings.prependPreloadingComplete);l.prependPreloadingCompleteTo.addClass("preloading-complete");setTimeout(S,l.settings.hidePreloaderDelay)}else l.settings.preloader.fadeOut(l.settings.hidePreloaderDelay,function(){clearInterval(l.defaultPreloader);S()});else S()}function g(t,n){var r=[];if(!n)for(var i=t;i>0;i--)l.frames.eq(l.settings.preloadTheseFrames[i-1]-1).find("img").each(function(){r.push(e(this)[0])});else for(var s=t;s>0;s--)r.push(e("body").find('img[src="'+l.settings.preloadTheseImages[s-1]+'"]'));return r}function y(t,n){function c(){var t=e(f),r=e(l);s&&(l.length?s.reject(u,t,r):s.resolve(u));e.isFunction(n)&&n.call(i,u,t,r)}function h(t,n){if(t.src===r||e.inArray(t,a)!==-1)return;a.push(t);n?l.push(t):f.push(t);e.data(t,"imagesLoaded",{isBroken:n,src:t.src});o&&s.notifyWith(e(t),[n,u,e(f),e(l)]);if(u.length===a.length){setTimeout(c);u.unbind(".imagesLoaded")}}var r="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw==",i=t,s=e.isFunction(e.Deferred)?e.Deferred():0,o=e.isFunction(s.notify),u=i.find("img").add(i.filter("img")),a=[],f=[],l=[];e.isPlainObject(n)&&e.each(n,function(e,t){e==="callback"?n=t:s&&s[e](t)});u.length?u.bind("load.imagesLoaded error.imagesLoaded",function(e){h(e.target,e.type==="error")}).each(function(t,n){var i=n.src,s=e.data(n,"imagesLoaded");if(s&&s.src===i){h(n,s.isBroken);return}if(n.complete&&n.naturalWidth!==undefined){h(n,n.naturalWidth===0||n.naturalHeight===0);return}if(n.readyState||n.complete){n.src=r;n.src=i}}):c()}function S(){function t(e,t){var i,s;for(s in t){s==="left"||s==="right"?i=n[s]:i=s;e===parseFloat(i)&&r(l,t[s])}}function s(){l.canvas.on("touchmove.sequence",o);c=null;p=!1}function o(e){l.settings.swipePreventsDefault&&e.preventDefault();if(p){var t=e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX,n=e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY,i=c-t,o=h-n;if(Math.abs(i)>=l.settings.swipeThreshold){s();i>0?r(l,l.settings.swipeEvents.left):r(l,l.settings.swipeEvents.right)}else if(Math.abs(o)>=l.settings.swipeThreshold){s();o>0?r(l,l.settings.swipeEvents.down):r(l,l.settings.swipeEvents.up)}}}function f(e){if(e.originalEvent.touches.length===1){c=e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;h=e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;p=!0;l.canvas.on("touchmove.sequence",o)}}e(l.settings.preloader).remove();l.nextButton=a(l,l.settings.nextButton,".sequence-next");l.prevButton=a(l,l.settings.prevButton,".sequence-prev");l.pauseButton=a(l,l.settings.pauseButton,".sequence-pause");l.pagination=a(l,l.settings.pagination,".sequence-pagination");l.nextButton!==undefined&&l.nextButton!==!1&&l.settings.showNextButtonOnInit===!0&&l.nextButton.show();l.prevButton!==undefined&&l.prevButton!==!1&&l.settings.showPrevButtonOnInit===!0&&l.prevButton.show();l.pauseButton!==undefined&&l.pauseButton!==!1&&l.settings.showPauseButtonOnInit===!0&&l.pauseButton.show();if(l.settings.pauseIcon!==!1){l.pauseIcon=a(l,l.settings.pauseIcon,".sequence-pause-icon");l.pauseIcon!==undefined&&l.pauseIcon.hide()}else l.pauseIcon=undefined;if(l.pagination!==undefined&&l.pagination!==!1){l.paginationLinks=l.pagination.children();l.paginationLinks.on("click.sequence",function(){var t=e(this).index()+1;l.goTo(t)});l.settings.showPaginationOnInit===!0&&l.pagination.show()}l.nextFrameID=l.settings.startingFrameID;if(l.settings.hashTags===!0){l.frames.each(function(){l.frameHashID.push(e(this).prop(l.getHashTagFrom))});l.currentHashTag=location.hash.replace("#","");if(l.currentHashTag===undefined||l.currentHashTag==="")l.nextFrameID=l.settings.startingFrameID;else{l.frameHashIndex=e.inArray(l.currentHashTag,l.frameHashID);l.frameHashIndex!==-1?l.nextFrameID=l.frameHashIndex+1:l.nextFrameID=l.settings.startingFrameID}}l.nextFrame=l.frames.eq(l.nextFrameID-1);l.nextFrameChildren=l.nextFrame.children();l.pagination!==undefined&&e(l.paginationLinks[l.settings.startingFrameID-1]).addClass("current");if(l.transitionsSupported)if(!l.settings.animateStartingFrameIn){l.currentFrameID=l.nextFrameID;l.settings.moveActiveFrameToTop&&l.nextFrame.css("z-index",l.numberOfFrames);i(l.prefix,l.nextFrameChildren,"0s");l.nextFrame.addClass("animate-in");if(l.settings.hashTags&&l.settings.hashChangesOnFirstFrame){l.currentHashTag=l.nextFrame.prop(l.getHashTagFrom);document.location.hash="#"+l.currentHashTag}setTimeout(function(){i(l.prefix,l.nextFrameChildren,"")},100);u(l,!0,l.settings.autoPlayDelay)}else if(l.settings.reverseAnimationsWhenNavigatingBackwards&&l.settings.autoPlayDirection-1&&l.settings.animateStartingFrameIn){i(l.prefix,l.nextFrameChildren,"0s");l.nextFrame.addClass("animate-out");l.goTo(l.nextFrameID,-1,!0)}else l.goTo(l.nextFrameID,1,!0);else{l.container.addClass("sequence-fallback");l.currentFrameID=l.nextFrameID;if(l.settings.hashTags&&l.settings.hashChangesOnFirstFrame){l.currentHashTag=l.nextFrame.prop(l.getHashTagFrom);document.location.hash="#"+l.currentHashTag}l.frames.addClass("animate-in");l.frames.not(":eq("+(l.nextFrameID-1)+")").css({display:"none",opacity:0});u(l,!0,l.settings.autoPlayDelay)}l.nextButton!==undefined&&l.nextButton.bind("click.sequence",function(){l.next()});l.prevButton!==undefined&&l.prevButton.bind("click.sequence",function(){l.prev()});l.pauseButton!==undefined&&l.pauseButton.bind("click.sequence",function(){l.pause(!0)});if(l.settings.keyNavigation){var n={left:37,right:39};e(document).bind("keydown.sequence",function(e){var n=String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);if(n>0&&n<=l.numberOfFrames&&l.settings.numericKeysGoToFrames){l.nextFrameID=n;l.goTo(l.nextFrameID)}t(e.keyCode,l.settings.keyEvents);t(e.keyCode,l.settings.customKeyEvents)})}l.settings.pauseOnHover&&l.settings.autoPlay&&!l.hasTouch&&l.canvas.on({"mouseenter.sequence":function(){l.isBeingHoveredOver=!0;l.isHardPaused||l.pause()},"mouseleave.sequence":function(){l.isBeingHoveredOver=!1;l.isHardPaused||l.unpause()}});l.settings.hashTags&&e(window).bind("hashchange.sequence",function(){var t=location.hash.replace("#","");if(l.currentHashTag!==t){l.currentHashTag=t;l.frameHashIndex=e.inArray(l.currentHashTag,l.frameHashID);if(l.frameHashIndex!==-1){l.nextFrameID=l.frameHashIndex+1;l.goTo(l.nextFrameID)}}});if(l.settings.swipeNavigation&&l.hasTouch){var c,h,p=!1;l.canvas.on("touchstart.sequence",f)}}var l=this;l.container=e(n);l.canvas=l.container.children(".sequence-canvas");l.frames=l.canvas.children("li");try{Modernizr.prefixed;if(Modernizr.prefixed===undefined)throw"undefined"}catch(c){f.modernizr()}var h={WebkitTransition:"-webkit-",MozTransition:"-moz-",OTransition:"-o-",msTransition:"-ms-",transition:""},p={WebkitTransition:"webkitTransitionEnd.sequence webkitAnimationEnd.sequence",MozTransition:"transitionend.sequence animationend.sequence",OTransition:"otransitionend.sequence oanimationend.sequence",msTransition:"MSTransitionEnd.sequence MSAnimationEnd.sequence",transition:"transitionend.sequence animationend.sequence"};l.prefix=h[Modernizr.prefixed("transition")],l.transitionProperties={},l.transitionEnd=p[Modernizr.prefixed("transition")],l.numberOfFrames=l.frames.length,l.transitionsSupported=l.prefix!==undefined?!0:!1,l.hasTouch="ontouchstart"in window?!0:!1,l.isPaused=!1,l.isBeingHoveredOver=!1,l.container.removeClass("sequence-destroyed");l.paused=function(){},l.unpaused=function(){},l.beforeNextFrameAnimatesIn=function(){},l.afterNextFrameAnimatesIn=function(){},l.beforeCurrentFrameAnimatesOut=function(){},l.afterCurrentFrameAnimatesOut=function(){},l.afterLoaded=function(){};l.destroyed=function(){};l.settings=e.extend({},o,s);l.settings.preloader=a(l,l.settings.preloader,".sequence-preloader");l.isStartingFrame=l.settings.animateStartingFrameIn?!0:!1;l.settings.unpauseDelay=l.settings.unpauseDelay===null?l.settings.autoPlayDelay:l.settings.unpauseDelay;l.getHashTagFrom=l.settings.hashDataAttribute?"data-sequence-hashtag":"id";l.frameHashID=[];l.direction=l.settings.autoPlayDirection;l.settings.hideFramesUntilPreloaded&&l.settings.preloader!==undefined&&l.settings.preloader!==!1&&l.frames.hide();l.prefix==="-o-"&&(l.transitionsSupported=f.operaTest());l.frames.removeClass("animate-in");var v=l.settings.preloadTheseFrames.length,m=l.settings.preloadTheseImages.length;if(l.settings.preloader===undefined||l.settings.preloader===!1||v===0&&m===0)if(t===!0){d();e(this).unbind("load.sequence")}else e(window).bind("load.sequence",function(){d();e(this).unbind("load.sequence")});else{var b=g(v),w=g(m,!0),E=e(b.concat(w));y(E,d)}}var t=!1;e(window).bind("load",function(){t=!0});n.prototype={startAutoPlay:function(e){var t=this;e=e===undefined?t.settings.autoPlayDelay:e;t.unpause();u(t);t.autoPlayTimer=setTimeout(function(){t.settings.autoPlayDirection===1?t.next():t.prev()},e)},stopAutoPlay:function(){var e=this;e.pause(!0);clearTimeout(e.autoPlayTimer)},pause:function(e){var t=this;if(!t.isSoftPaused){if(t.pauseButton!==undefined){t.pauseButton.addClass("paused");t.pauseIcon!==undefined&&t.pauseIcon.show()}t.paused();t.isSoftPaused=!0;t.isHardPaused=e?!0:!1;t.isPaused=!0;u(t)}else t.unpause()},unpause:function(e){var t=this;if(t.pauseButton!==undefined){t.pauseButton.removeClass("paused");t.pauseIcon!==undefined&&t.pauseIcon.hide()}t.isSoftPaused=!1;t.isHardPaused=!1;t.isPaused=!1;if(!t.active){e!==!1&&t.unpaused();u(t,!0,t.settings.unpauseDelay)}else t.delayUnpause=!0},next:function(){var e=this;e.nextFrameID=e.currentFrameID!==e.numberOfFrames?e.currentFrameID+1:1;e.active===!1||e.active===undefined?e.goTo(e.nextFrameID,1):e.goTo(e.nextFrameID,1,!0)},prev:function(){var e=this;e.nextFrameID=e.currentFrameID===1?e.numberOfFrames:e.currentFrameID-1;e.active===!1||e.active===undefined?e.goTo(e.nextFrameID,-1):e.goTo(e.nextFrameID,-1,!0)},goTo:function(t,n,r){var o=this;t=parseFloat(t);var a=r===!0?0:o.settings.transitionThreshold;if(t===o.currentFrameID||o.settings.navigationSkip&&o.navigationSkipThresholdActive||!o.settings.navigationSkip&&o.active||!o.transitionsSupported&&o.active||!o.settings.cycle&&n===1&&o.currentFrameID===o.numberOfFrames||!o.settings.cycle&&n===-1&&o.currentFrameID===1||o.settings.preventReverseSkipping&&o.direction!==n&&o.active)return!1;if(o.settings.navigationSkip&&o.active){o.navigationSkipThresholdActive=!0;o.settings.fadeFrameWhenSkipped&&o.nextFrame.stop().animate({opacity:0},o.settings.fadeFrameTime);clearTimeout(o.transitionThresholdTimer);setTimeout(function(){o.navigationSkipThresholdActive=!1},o.settings.navigationSkipThreshold)}if(!o.active||o.settings.navigationSkip){o.active=!0;u(o);n===undefined?o.direction=t>o.currentFrameID?1:-1:o.direction=n;o.currentFrame=o.canvas.children(".animate-in");o.nextFrame=o.frames.eq(t-1);o.currentFrameChildren=o.currentFrame.children();o.nextFrameChildren=o.nextFrame.children();if(o.pagination!==undefined){o.paginationLinks.removeClass("current");e(o.paginationLinks[t-1]).addClass("current")}if(o.transitionsSupported){if(o.currentFrame.length!==undefined){o.beforeCurrentFrameAnimatesOut();o.settings.moveActiveFrameToTop&&o.currentFrame.css("z-index",1);i(o.prefix,o.nextFrameChildren,"0s");if(!o.settings.reverseAnimationsWhenNavigatingBackwards||o.direction===1){o.nextFrame.removeClass("animate-out");i(o.prefix,o.currentFrameChildren,"")}else if(o.settings.reverseAnimationsWhenNavigatingBackwards&&o.direction===-1){o.nextFrame.addClass("animate-out");s(o)}}else o.isStartingFrame=!1;o.active=!0;o.currentFrame.unbind(o.transitionEnd);o.nextFrame.unbind(o.transitionEnd);o.settings.fadeFrameWhenSkipped&&o.settings.navigationSkip&&o.nextFrame.css("opacity",1);o.beforeNextFrameAnimatesIn();o.settings.moveActiveFrameToTop&&o.nextFrame.css("z-index",o.numberOfFrames);if(!o.settings.reverseAnimationsWhenNavigatingBackwards||o.direction===1){setTimeout(function(){i(o.prefix,o.nextFrameChildren,"");f(o,o.nextFrame,o.nextFrameChildren,"in");(o.afterCurrentFrameAnimatesOut!=="function () {}"||o.settings.transitionThreshold===!0&&r!==!0)&&f(o,o.currentFrame,o.currentFrameChildren,"out",!0,1)},50);setTimeout(function(){if(o.settings.transitionThreshold===!1||o.settings.transitionThreshold===0||r===!0){o.currentFrame.toggleClass("animate-out animate-in");o.nextFrame.addClass("animate-in")}else{o.currentFrame.toggleClass("animate-out animate-in");o.settings.transitionThreshold!==!0&&(o.transitionThresholdTimer=setTimeout(function(){o.nextFrame.addClass("animate-in")},a))}},50)}else if(o.settings.reverseAnimationsWhenNavigatingBackwards&&o.direction===-1){setTimeout(function(){i(o.prefix,o.currentFrameChildren,"");i(o.prefix,o.nextFrameChildren,"");s(o);f(o,o.nextFrame,o.nextFrameChildren,"in");(o.afterCurrentFrameAnimatesOut!=="function () {}"||o.settings.transitionThreshold===!0&&r!==!0)&&f(o,o.currentFrame,o.currentFrameChildren,"out",!0,-1)},50);setTimeout(function(){if(o.settings.transitionThreshold===!1||o.settings.transitionThreshold===0||r===!0){o.currentFrame.removeClass("animate-in");o.nextFrame.toggleClass("animate-out animate-in")}else{o.currentFrame.removeClass("animate-in");o.settings.transitionThreshold!==!0&&(o.transitionThresholdTimer=setTimeout(function(){o.nextFrame.toggleClass("animate-out animate-in")},a))}},50)}}else{function c(){l(o);o.active=!1;u(o,!0,o.settings.autoPlayDelay)}switch(o.settings.fallback.theme){case"fade":o.frames.css({position:"relative"});o.beforeCurrentFrameAnimatesOut();o.currentFrame=o.frames.eq(o.currentFrameID-1);o.currentFrame.animate({opacity:0},o.settings.fallback.speed,function(){o.currentFrame.css({display:"none","z-index":"1"});o.afterCurrentFrameAnimatesOut();o.beforeNextFrameAnimatesIn();o.nextFrame.css({display:"block","z-index":o.numberOfFrames}).animate({opacity:1},500,function(){o.afterNextFrameAnimatesIn()});c()});o.frames.css({position:"relative"});break;case"slide":default:var h={},p={},d={};if(o.direction===1){h.left="-100%";p.left="100%"}else{h.left="100%";p.left="-100%"}d.left="0";d.opacity=1;o.currentFrame=o.frames.eq(o.currentFrameID-1);o.beforeCurrentFrameAnimatesOut();o.currentFrame.animate(h,o.settings.fallback.speed,function(){o.currentFrame.css({display:"none","z-index":"1"});o.afterCurrentFrameAnimatesOut()});o.beforeNextFrameAnimatesIn();o.nextFrame.show().css(p);o.nextFrame.css({display:"block","z-index":o.numberOfFrames}).animate(d,o.settings.fallback.speed,function(){c();o.afterNextFrameAnimatesIn()})}}o.currentFrameID=t}},destroy:function(t){var n=this;n.container.addClass("sequence-destroyed");n.nextButton!==undefined&&n.nextButton.unbind("click.sequence");n.prevButton!==undefined&&n.prevButton.unbind("click.sequence");n.pauseButton!==undefined&&n.pauseButton.unbind("click.sequence");n.pagination!==undefined&&n.paginationLinks.unbind("click.sequence");e(document).unbind("keydown.sequence");n.canvas.unbind("mouseenter.sequence, mouseleave.sequence, touchstart.sequence, touchmove.sequence");e(window).unbind("hashchange.sequence");n.stopAutoPlay();clearTimeout(n.transitionThresholdTimer);n.canvas.children("li").remove();n.canvas.prepend(n.frames);n.frames.removeClass("animate-in animate-out").removeAttr("style");n.frames.eq(n.currentFrameID-1).addClass("animate-in");n.nextButton!==undefined&&n.nextButton!==!1&&n.nextButton.hide();n.prevButton!==undefined&&n.prevButton!==!1&&n.prevButton.hide();n.pauseButton!==undefined&&n.pauseButton!==!1&&n.pauseButton.hide();n.pauseIcon!==undefined&&n.pauseIcon!==!1&&n.pauseIcon.hide();n.pagination!==undefined&&n.pagination!==!1&&n.pagination.hide();t!==undefined&&t();n.destroyed();n.container.removeData()}};var r=function(e,t){switch(t){case"next":e.next();break;case"prev":e.prev();break;case"pause":e.pause(!0)}},i=function(e,t,n){t.css(o(e,{"transition-duration":n,"transition-delay":n,"transition-timing-function":""}))},s=function(t){var n=[],r=[];t.currentFrameChildren.each(function(){n.push(parseFloat(e(this).css(t.prefix+"transition-duration").replace("s",""))+parseFloat(e(this).css(t.prefix+"transition-delay").replace("s","")))});t.nextFrameChildren.each(function(){r.push(parseFloat(e(this).css(t.prefix+"transition-duration").replace("s",""))+parseFloat(e(this).css(t.prefix+"transition-delay").replace("s","")))});var i=Math.max.apply(Math,n),s=Math.max.apply(Math,r),u=i-s,a=0,f=0;u<0&&!t.settings.preventDelayWhenReversingAnimations?a=Math.abs(u):u>0&&(f=Math.abs(u));var l=function(n,r,i,s){r.each(function(){var r=parseFloat(e(this).css(t.prefix+"transition-duration").replace("s","")),u=parseFloat(e(this).css(t.prefix+"transition-delay").replace("s","")),a=e(this).css(t.prefix+"transition-timing-function");if(a.indexOf("cubic-bezier")>=0){var f=a.replace("cubic-bezier(","").replace(")","").split(",");e.each(f,function(e,t){f[e]=parseFloat(t)});var l=[1-f[2],1-f[3],1-f[0],1-f[1]];a="cubic-bezier("+l+")"}else a="linear";var c=r+u;n["transition-duration"]=r+"s";n["transition-delay"]=i-c+s+"s";n["transition-timing-function"]=a;e(this).css(o(t.prefix,n))})};l(t.transitionProperties,t.currentFrameChildren,i,a);l(t.transitionProperties,t.nextFrameChildren,s,f)},o=function(e,t){var n={};for(var r in t)n[e+r]=t[r];return n},u=function(e,t,n){if(t===!0){if(e.settings.autoPlay&&!e.isSoftPaused){clearTimeout(e.autoPlayTimer);e.autoPlayTimer=setTimeout(function(){e.settings.autoPlayDirection===1?e.next():e.prev()},n)}}else clearTimeout(e.autoPlayTimer)},a=function(t,n,r){switch(n){case!1:return undefined;case!0:r===".sequence-preloader"&&c.defaultPreloader(t.container,t.transitionsSupported,t.prefix);return e(r);default:return e(n)}},f=function(t,n,r,i,s,o){if(i==="out")var u=function(){t.afterCurrentFrameAnimatesOut();t.settings.transitionThreshold===!0&&(o===1?t.nextFrame.addClass("animate-in"):o===-1&&t.nextFrame.toggleClass("animate-out animate-in"))};else if(i==="in")var u=function(){t.afterNextFrameAnimatesIn();l(t);t.active=!1;if(!t.isHardPaused&&!t.isBeingHoveredOver)if(!t.delayUnpause)t.unpause(!1);else{t.delayUnpause=!1;t.unpause()}};r.data("animationEnded",!1);n.bind(t.transitionEnd,function(i){e(i.target).data("animationEnded",!0);var s=!0;r.each(function(){if(e(this).data("animationEnded")===!1){s=!1;return!1}});if(s){n.unbind(t.transitionEnd);u()}})},l=function(t){if(t.settings.hashTags){t.currentHashTag=t.nextFrame.prop(t.getHashTagFrom);t.frameHashIndex=e.inArray(t.currentHashTag,t.frameHashID);if(t.frameHashIndex!==-1&&(t.settings.hashChangesOnFirstFrame||!t.isStartingFrame||!t.transitionsSupported)){t.nextFrameID=t.frameHashIndex+1;document.location.hash="#"+t.currentHashTag}else{t.nextFrameID=t.settings.startingFrameID;t.isStartingFrame=!1}}},c={modernizr:function(){window.Modernizr=function(e,t,n){function r(e){v.cssText=e}function i(e,t){return r(prefixes.join(e+";")+(t||""))}function s(e,t){return typeof e===t}function o(e,t){return!!~(""+e).indexOf(t)}function u(e,t){for(var r in e){var i=e[r];if(!o(i,"-")&&v[i]!==n)return t=="pfx"?i:!0}return!1}function a(e,t,r){for(var i in e){var o=t[e[i]];if(o!==n)return r===!1?e[i]:s(o,"function")?o.bind(r||t):o}return!1}function f(e,t,n){var r=e.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+e.slice(1),i=(e+" "+b.join(r+" ")+r).split(" ");return s(t,"string")||s(t,"undefined")?u(i,t):(i=(e+" "+w.join(r+" ")+r).split(" "),a(i,t,n))}var l="2.6.1",c={},h=t.documentElement,p="modernizr",d=t.createElement(p),v=d.style,m,g={}.toString,y="Webkit Moz O ms",b=y.split(" "),w=y.toLowerCase().split(" "),E={svg:"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"},S={},x={},T={},N=[],C=N.slice,k,L={}.hasOwnProperty,A;!s(L,"undefined")&&!s(L.call,"undefined")?A=function(e,t){return L.call(e,t)}:A=function(e,t){return t in e&&s(e.constructor.prototype[t],"undefined")},Function.prototype.bind||(Function.prototype.bind=function(e){var t=self;if(typeof t!="function")throw new TypeError;var n=C.call(arguments,1),r=function(){if(self instanceof r){var i=function(){};i.prototype=t.prototype;var s=new i,o=t.apply(s,n.concat(C.call(arguments)));return Object(o)===o?o:s}return t.apply(e,n.concat(C.call(arguments)))};return r}),S.svg=function(){return!!t.createElementNS&&!!t.createElementNS(E.svg,"svg").createSVGRect};for(var O in S)A(S,O)&&(k=O.toLowerCase(),c[k]=S[O](),N.push((c[k]?"":"no-")+k));return c.addTest=function(e,t){if(typeof e=="object")for(var r in e)A(e,r)&&c.addTest(r,e[r]);else{e=e.toLowerCase();if(c[e]!==n)return c;t=typeof t=="function"?t():t,enableClasses&&(h.className+=" "+(t?"":"no-")+e),c[e]=t}return c},r(""),d=m=null,c._version=l,c._domPrefixes=w,c._cssomPrefixes=b,c.testProp=function(e){return u([e])},c.testAllProps=f,c.prefixed=function(e,t,n){return t?f(e,t,n):f(e,"pfx")},c}(self,self.document)},defaultPreloader:function(t,n,r){var i='<div class="sequence-preloader"><svg class="preloading" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle class="circle" cx="6" cy="6" r="6" /><circle class="circle" cx="22" cy="6" r="6" /><circle class="circle" cx="38" cy="6" r="6" /></svg></div>';e("head").append("<style>.sequence-preloader{height: 100%;position: absolute;width: 100%;z-index: 999999;}@"+r+"keyframes preload{0%{opacity: 1;}50%{opacity: 0;}100%{opacity: 1;}}.sequence-preloader .preloading .circle{fill: #ff9442;display: inline-block;height: 12px;position: relative;top: -50%;width: 12px;"+r+"animation: preload 1s infinite; animation: preload 1s infinite;}.preloading{display:block;height: 12px;margin: 0 auto;top: 50%;margin-top:-6px;position: relative;width: 48px;}.sequence-preloader .preloading .circle:nth-child(2){"+r+"animation-delay: .15s; animation-delay: .15s;}.sequence-preloader .preloading .circle:nth-child(3){"+r+"animation-delay: .3s; animation-delay: .3s;}.preloading-complete{opacity: 0;visibility: hidden;"+r+"transition-duration: 1s; transition-duration: 1s;}div.inline{background-color: #ff9442; margin-right: 4px; float: left;}</style>");t.prepend(i);if(!Modernizr.svg&&!n){e(".sequence-preloader").prepend('<div class="preloading"><div class="circle inline"></div><div class="circle inline"></div><div class="circle inline"></div></div>');setInterval(function(){e(".sequence-preloader .circle").fadeToggle(500)},500)}else n||setInterval(function(){e(".sequence-preloader").fadeToggle(500)},500)},operaTest:function(){e("body").append('<span id="sequence-opera-test"></span>');var t=e("#sequence-opera-test");t.css("-o-transition","1s");return t.css("-o-transition")!=="1s"?!1:!0}},h={startingFrameID:1,cycle:!0,animateStartingFrameIn:!1,transitionThreshold:!1,reverseAnimationsWhenNavigatingBackwards:!0,preventDelayWhenReversingAnimations:!1,moveActiveFrameToTop:!0,autoPlay:!1,autoPlayDirection:1,autoPlayDelay:5e3,navigationSkip:!0,navigationSkipThreshold:250,fadeFrameWhenSkipped:!0,fadeFrameTime:150,preventReverseSkipping:!1,nextButton:!1,showNextButtonOnInit:!0,prevButton:!1,showPrevButtonOnInit:!0,pauseButton:!1,unpauseDelay:null,pauseOnHover:!0,pauseIcon:!1,showPauseButtonOnInit:!0,pagination:!1,showPaginationOnInit:!0,preloader:!1,preloadTheseFrames:[1],preloadTheseImages:[],hideFramesUntilPreloaded:!0,prependPreloadingComplete:!0,hidePreloaderUsingCSS:!0,hidePreloaderDelay:0,keyNavigation:!0,numericKeysGoToFrames:!0,keyEvents:{left:"prev",right:"next"},customKeyEvents:{},swipeNavigation:!0,swipeThreshold:20,swipePreventsDefault:!1,swipeEvents:{left:"prev",right:"next",up:!1,down:!1},hashTags:!1,hashDataAttribute:!1,hashChangesOnFirstFrame:!1,fallback:{theme:"slide",speed:500}};e.fn.sequence=function(t){return this.each(function(){e.data(this,"sequence")||e.data(this,"sequence",new n(e(this),t,h,c))})}})(jQuery);
```

Comment: No... that doesn't resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try using $.noConflict(); in the header before calling the toTop script.

The documentation may be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)